# If $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}=\frac{1}{14},$then find the value of $f(\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: limits, functions

Let $f:R\to R$ be a continuous odd function,which vanishes at exactly one point and $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$.Suppose that $F(x)=\int_{-1}^{x}f(t)dt,\hspace{1cm}\forall x\in[-1,2]$,and $G(x)=\int_{-1}^{x}t|f(f(t))|dt\hspace{1cm} \forall x\in[-1,2]$.If  $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}=\frac{1}{14},$then find the value of $f(\frac{1}{2})$

---

This question was asked in JEE Advanced.I reached near completion but has one doubt.
$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}$ is in $\frac{0}{0}$ form.As $F(1)=\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt=0,f(x)$ being a odd function and $G(1)=\int_{-1}^{1}t|f(f(t))|dt=0$.As the integrand being an odd function.
Then i applied L Hospital rule,limit becomes $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{F'(x)}{G'(x)}$,where F'(x) and G'(x) are derivatives of F(x) and G(x) respectively.
$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{F'(x)}{G'(x)}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)}{x|f(f(x))|}=\frac{f(1)}{|f(f(1))|}=\frac{1}{2|f(\frac{1}{2})|}=\frac{1}{14}$
$|f(\frac{1}{2})|=7\Rightarrow f(\frac{1}{2})=\pm 7 $
But in the answer only $7$ is given.I am not clear why have they ignored $-7$.Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They tell you that it vanishes at exactly one point. But if $f(x)$ is odd, then $f(0) = 0$. So $f(\frac{1}{2}) > 0$ by IVT.

Comment: How did you get $f(0)=0$

Comment: The function is odd, so $f(0) = f(-0) = -f(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

As the function is odd and vanishes at only one point $f(0)$=$0$ and so $f(\frac{1}{2})$ should be greater than $f(0)$.Since $f(0)$=$0$  ;$f(\frac{1}{2})$ should be greater than zero hence $-7$ is rejected.